# $.get command in jQuery goes wrong

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am new in jQuery and need help to figure out why $.get does not reply.

Let me explain what I have: There is a main index.php as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>  <meta charset="utf-8"> </head> 
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reqhan.js"> </script>
  <input id="string" type="text" />
  <input id="button" type= "button" value="Go" />
    <div id="div"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

the js/reqhan.js contains

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
alert('1');
$('#button').click(function() {
$.get('php/reverse.php',{input: string},function(data){alert('2');});
    $('#div').text(data);
    alert('3');

 });
 });
```

and reverse.php contains a simple code (I pasted here but does not preview it) that gets the text from reqhan.js file and returns an echo message.

when running the code on Google Chrome, the first alert is shown but not the  rest and of course the `$('#div').text(data);' doesn't send back the data to the js file.

Please let me know if further info is required.
many thanks.

Comment: Anything in the console (CTRL + Shift + J)?

Comment: with jquery mobile, you should use the event `pageinit` instead of `ready` (see http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: if your going user input -> script -> php ->user gui. that sounds to me to be more along the lines of ajax, in that case, since your php sccript interacts with the process, i personally would love to see it

Comment: What do you mean Grim by anything? There is one error in the console for the jqery.js file. It throws Uncaught TypeError: illegal invocation

Comment: @tmuguet: thanks for your effort. I am actually using the code in desktop as of now for learning purpose and I use jquery.js not jquerym. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your callback function before you do anything with the data

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert('1');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.get('php/reverse.php',{input: string},function(data){
            alert('2');
            $('#div').text(data);
            alert('3');
        });
    });
});
```

Try to format your code so that each pair of brackets gets its own indentation. It should help catch small things like this.

Comment: Thanks @Colin Morelli, I used your code too, but no way. Only first alert pops up. When I comment the $.get and its {); lines, it works and second alert is shown. Here is one point, when I run the W3 "try it" code of get example (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get) using its online engine, it works. But when I run the same code on my browser, it fails. Is there anything wrong with my browser? I have installed PhP and it works fine when i call <? Php phpinfo() ?>. pls help

Comment: @Espanta You need to make sure the file you are calling `php/reverse.php` actually exists and is working. Go to the page directly in your browser like this: `php/reverse.php?input=hello`. Remember that, because you don't have a slash in front of the URL - the path is relative. If your javascript is at `www.yourdomain.com/myfolder/myfile.html` then the php script should be in `www.yourdomain.com/myfolder/php/reverse.php`

Comment: thanks guys, I finally did it, but I guess it was something wrong with the web server not my code. Thanks once more.